# Vim annoying automatic unindents while editing php files

Tags: php, vim, indentation

Consider this scenario :

```
function name() {
   $query = "select { some-value ";
}
```

Now, While typing the closing curly brace `}`, the line automatically indents to the left side like this :

```
function name() {
$query = "select { some-value }";
}
```

This is very much annoying. Each time, I have to indent it once again to the right. Secondly, consider this :

```
Class Name {
    $var = 'val'
}
```

Now, when I type semicolon `;`, the line automatically indents to the left like this :

```
Class Name {
$var = 'val';
}
```

I also tried downloading the `php-correct-indenting` plugin and putting it inside the `~/.vim/indent/` directory, but still the same problem exists. BTW, I use vim 7.4.

Comment: Can you share your `.vimrc`?

Comment: @Conner Here is the pastebin link to my `.vimrc` file : http://pastebin.com/9c2bUagP

Comment: Try `smartindent` instead of `autoindent`.

Comment: @Conner still no luck

Comment: Using your `.vimrc` without the same issues. Must be a plugin.

Comment: @Conner Thanks a lot. Will try to figure out what it is.

Comment: What does `:verbose set smartindent? ai? indentexpr?` tell you?  There is not much point in scrutinizing the vimrc file if the options are set somewhere else.  (I had a quick look:  Line 28 is the part that interests me the most.)  BTW, I hope you mean `~/.vim/indent/` and not `/.vim/indent/`.

Comment: @benjifisher ok, `indentexpr` was set in a vim indent file in the `eclim` directory like this : 

    `indentexpr=EclimGetHtmlIndent(v:lnum) 
        Last set from ~/.vim/eclim/indent/html.vim`

Removing the `eclim` directory worked! Thanks a lot. Would you like the add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can figure out where the relevant options were set with

```
:verbose set smartindent? ai? indentexpr?
```

There is not much point in scrutinizing the vimrc file if the options are set somewhere else. (I had a quick look: Line 28 is the part that interests me the most.) BTW, I hope you mean `~/.vim/indent/` and not `/.vim/indent/`.

Comment: `indentexpr` was set in a vim indent file in the `eclim` directory like this : `indentexpr=EclimGetHtmlIndent(v:lnum) Last set from ~/.vim/eclim/indent/html.vim` Removing the `eclim` directory worked!